# Highcharts solid gauge with tick mark over the bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to use Highchart's Solid Gauge chart to render something like this:

[image]

The closest I've gotten is [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/827jw9L1/3/):

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge'
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: null,
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  pane: {
    size: '100%',
    startAngle: -120,
    endAngle: 120,
    background: {
      innerRadius: '75%', 
      outerRadius: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
      borderWidth: 0,
      shape: 'arc'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      innerRadius: '75%',
      radius: '100%',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },      
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickPositions: [35],
    tickColor: '#000000',
    tickPosition: 'inside',
    tickLength: 60,
    tickWidth: 4
  },
  series: [{
    data: [40]
  }]
});
```

Which looks like:

[image]

The main problem is with the black tick mark:

- It draws behind the bar, but I want it to draw over the bar
- It is not centered over the bar

How can this be done with Highcharts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `zIndex` in plotOptions and yAxis

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/dvoj5wvh/4/) Demo

```
 plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      innerRadius: '75%',
      radius: '100%',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        useHTML: true,
        zIndex: 1000 //added
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },      
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickPositions: [35],
    tickColor: '#000000',
    tickPosition: 'inside',
    tickLength: 50,
    tickWidth: 8,
    zIndex: 100, //added
  },
```

Comment: Perfect! Now is there any way to center the tick over the bar, like my mockup image?

Comment: I tried but not working with `tickLength: -50,` or `tickPosition: 'outside',`

Comment: Ok. Seems it cannot be done. Is it possible to use the [freeform drawing commands](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/freeform-drawing) to draw a custom tick mark? The problem I have is knowing at what angle to draw it... that's a big part of what the chart is doing for us.

Comment: Yeah, I'll fiddle with this but it's probably not worth it. Thanks for your help, accepting your answer. Cheers.